# Linking header in multiple HTML files

Tags: html, header, navbar

I am working on a website for a project and I have a navigation bar that is going to be on many pages. I can not find a way to link that HTML code to all the pages without copy and pasting it into every page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If your server has PHP you could use PHP includes http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Save your html header out there as a partial (without body or whatnot) as `pageheader.html`.  Immediately following the `<body>` tag (or wherever you'd like it to be included on the page) in the individual pages, include the following:

```
<!--#include virtual="/pageheader.html" -->
```

That should do the trick, provided the individual pages are saved as `.shtml` files, rather than plain `.html` files.